# Protecting electronics from electrical surges - plugs with fuses

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, surge-suppression

i was just wondering why the UK 3 pin plug has a fuse ? in South Africa the the Grid is significantly more volatile and lighting strikes abundant ( in the area i live in anyway)

i have moved here from the UK and was wondering why they dont sell any plugs with fuses , it just seems logical to me ..

any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: A fuse is not a surge protector. See: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51897/what-does-a-surge-protector-do-that-a-breaker-doesnt/51903#51903

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UK uses fused plugs because instead of using individual spurs or "home runs" rated at the receptacle rating to feed a few outlets at a time, they put all receptacles on a single "ring main" circuit that can provide more current (32A is typical) than appliances and their cords can handle (16A max, although smaller is common with BS1363 plugs).  It has nothing to do with surges or grid instability.